# Prove that one span is equal to another

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have question according to one of my linear algebra final exam course, i don't remember how task was written, but it was about proving that:
$span(v_1,v_2,...,v_n) = span(v_1,v_1+v_2,v_2+v_3,...,v_{n-1}+v_n)$
vectors form some same vector space, v1,...,vn are linearly independent

My idea was to prove that second set of vectors is linear combination of first set, since span of linear combination of a set of vectors is equal to span of this set.

Comment: You're also given that $\;v_1,...,v_n\;$ are linearly independent...right?

Comment: Yes, question corrected

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** In general, you can use the following lemma

> **Lemma** Let $\{w_1,\cdots w_k\}\subset H$ ($H$ is a subspace) then 
>   $$
> span\{w_1,\cdots w_k\}\subset H
> $$

here the spans are subspaces. 
So, can you prove that each $v_i$ is in 
$$
span(v_1,v_1+v_2,v_2+v_3,...,v_{n-1}+v_n)\ ?
$$
Converse is easy.

**Note** Linear independence is not needed.